# How to grep lines in a cron job whose crontab appears to be deleted?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, grep, cron

I'm trying to search for a specific word in my cron job, which we'll call `word` for now.

The machine is an AWS server, and I've only ever used one username, so I do not think it is an issue of cron jobs being under a different user.

So, in the root directory, I do `egrep -r ".*word.*"` .  Nothing comes up.  I would assume the original crontab was deleted at some point, even though the process is still running.

However, when I do `crontab -l`, I comb through the entire output (takes a while), I can see that there definitely is a cronjob with this `word`.

What is the best way to grep lines in a cronjob?  Or, does egrep only work on certain types of files?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Wait. If you're doing this:

```
egrep -r ".*word.*"
```

It won't return because you haven't pointed `egrep` at a file to grep through. Generally, you use grep like this:

```
egrep "word" filename
egrep -r "word" directory/
egrep -r "word" *
```

You can grep the output of `crontab -l` like this:

```
crontab -l | egrep "word"
```

Other notes:

- the `.*word.*` is unnecessary, as `word` will match. It should be faster (greedy matching)
- `egrep -r word *` in your home directory wouldn't match the crontab, as that isn't stored in your homedir. (it's likely at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`, but that's not terribly relevant)

Comment: Good catch.  `egrep` with no filename args will read from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

you simply have to do:

```
crontab -l | grep 'word'
```

That's all.